# How to make a concern route DRYer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, dry

sometimes I need a concern route as a collection and sometimes as a member (sometimes I `have_many` galleries, and sometimes just `has_one`)

```
concern :single_galleriable do
  resource :gallery, concerns: :photoable do
    member do
      post :make_feature
    end
  end
end

concern :galleriable do
  resources :gallery, concerns: :photoable do
    member do
      post :make_feature
    end
  end
end
```

and then I would do

```
resources :somemodel, concerns: :single_galleriable
```

obviously, too wet..

can I use the concern as resource or resources according to my needs while the concern's content stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help, but you can use methods in your routes.rb file:

```
 #config/routes.rb (some of our actual code)

 #Methods have to be kept at the top
 def destroy_all
      collection do
        delete :destroy_all
        delete 'destroy(/:id)', action: 'destroy', as: 'multi_destroy'
      end
 end

 #General stuff
 resources :controller do
     destroy_all
 end
```

--

This means you could do something like this:

```
 #config/routes.rb

 #Methods have to be kept at the top
 def gallery type = true
      method = type ? "s" : ""
      self.send("resource#{method}") :gallery, concerns: :photoable do
          post :make_feature
      end
 end

 #General
 resources :controller do
     gallery false
 end
```

Comment: this is definitely a possibility, I won't accept it yet, as there maybe a way to do it in a cleaner way. Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks buddy - don't worry about accepting; it's much better to get the right solution

Comment: Btw I was going to test to get the `self.___` working - it will cause an error as it is now